# Django: Admin change form in popup with 'save and continue'

Tags: django, popup, request, admin

I am using django's `?_popup=1` to display a form in a popup. By default that form shows only the submit button with `name=_save`. This means that after saving the page returns to the change list page.

For my use case I modified it to use the submit button with the `name=_continue` behavior, which means it stays on the edit page.

After saving the `_popup` gets lost and the 'non-popup-optimized' edit page is displayed inside the popup.

I dug my way to the `response_change()` method in `contrib/admin/options.py` (Django 1.6, ln 956). The redirect there seems to no longer carry the `_popup` variable.

Does anyone know a way to make this work? Probably I am missing something, but googling didn't do it for me this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hacky solution, but i didn't found any better. Since there is always a redirect in response_change() to request.path, then we can't do any harm by changing it a bit.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if '_popup' in request.REQUEST:
            request.path += '?_popup=1'
        return super(MockupAreaAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L968

Try overriding:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

to:

```
if "_popup" in request.REQUEST:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path + "?_popup=1")
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```